# This code is for C++ , any idea how can i convert this code to C as in C the syntax are quite different

Tags: c, csv

I have a file name file.csv in which there are three columns and two rows. I have coded to read the data and store in a multidimensional array in C++.

```
// reading csv file and storing values in matrix r 
const int rows = 10;
const int cols = 3;
ifstream file("file.csv");
if (file.is_open()) {
    float r[rows][cols];
    for (int p = 0; p < rows; ++p) {  // Reading Data from File
        for (int q = 0; q < cols; ++q) {
            file >> r[p][q];
            file.get(); // Throw away the comma from values in csv file
        }
    }
```

This code is for C++ , any idea how can i convert this code to C as in C the syntax are quite different and throwing away the comma is not easy .

Edit: the csv files contains the float values

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that a few things will change, namely you will no longer be able to use streams.  That said, it's a fairly easy problem.

Also, there are a number of answers already on SO.  See the answer in this thread: [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: +1 for giving advice and not code.

Comment: Thanks man 
I am little bit confused at this point

char* tmp = strdup(line);

as in my case the file date is of 2 dimensional array so how can i store that data using this command 

Thanks again :)

Comment: @it'sPete fopen,fwrite and fread in C are stream based: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwrite.html

Comment: @user2828488 I don't understand your question. I would create a CSV parser with a seperator as an argument to parse the different fields. simply use fgets (which is stream based) to get each line then find 2 consecutive seperators in the result character array and store their position, then copy the characters between the current seperator and the next to the output.

Comment: sorry, I meant that you can't use the << and >> operators

Comment: Thanks 

Now I have this code

`/*
       * Read each line from the file.
       */
      for ( i = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file); ++i )
      {
         /*
          * Parse the comma-separated values from each line into 'array'.
          */
         for ( j = 0, ptr = buffer; j < ARRAYSIZE(*array); ++j, ++ptr )
         {
            array[i][j] = (float)strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
         }
   }
      fclose(file);
   }`
the problem is it's storing the integer values in array , 

any hint for storing the float values in array?

Comment: @user2828488 your `strtol` converts the number to long interger, thus losing the foat point precision. If you cast it back to float, it doesn't help, since the precision is already lost. You need to use `strtof` which will convert the string to float. So no cast is needed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the updated code you posted in the comments:**

`strtol` converts the number to long interger, thus losing the foat point precision. If you cast it back to float, it doesn't help, since the precision is already lost. You need to use `strtof` which will convert the string to float. So no cast is needed afterwards.