# How to load from .csv file into sql database using C

Tags: sql, c, unix, csv

I have a table created in myFile.csv. I wanted to load this table into SQL database. I am working in C language under unix environment. I went through some links but I didn't get any useful direction. Thanks.

Comment: 1) how parse see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a CSV file instead of a CVS file.  CSV stands for Comma Seperated Values.  To load data from C to a database you will need C libraries for the database that allow you to run SQL INSERT statements.  C isn't suited really well for this task in this day and age.  Java would likely be a better bet because because nearly all vendors provide JDBC drivers for this purpose.  If you insist on doing this in C you will likely be using ODBC drivers or a native library for your database on non-Windows platforms.  Some information about ODBC can be found at this [link](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question.

If you want to load a text file into an SQL database, you can do this usually with some helper program from the database in question. For MySQL, this could be [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) or [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html)

Answer (score 0):

not a real code snippet, but just guidelines...

1. read the file with fgets() , this will give you line by line output...
2. for each line, tokenize it using strtok

   char *brkt;
   for (item = strtok_r(line, ",", &brkt); line; line = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &brkt)) {

   }
3. connect to the database and send your query . i.e. mysqlconnect() for mysql