# Read comma separated values from a text file in C

Tags: c, string, file-io, file-handling

I am really new to C programming and this is a part of an assignment. I am trying to read a comma separated text file in the format:

```
 [value1], [value2]
```

in C and trying to pass them as string and int parameter into a function. I have tried using the sscanf() and even manipulation with fgetc() without much help. The space after the comma is proving to be a problem.

Example:

```
 2001, 102
 1314, 78
 0410, 910
 ...
```

Please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate - please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12911299/1726419

Comment: In fact, you can't possiby. The csv-format may contain quoted commas in the data fields and isn't a simple thing to program as a beginner. If you wouldn't solve the simplest case only, you could use a good library and the examples therein: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/

Comment: I'm sorry. I was on it last night and did not save the codes that did not give me proper output.

Comment: @SouradeepSinha why don't you give it another try before asking here? If it's an assignement, you are supposed to learn from it ...

Comment: @rubberboots I am not allowed to read from a csv file. The file would have a .dat extension having text values.

Comment: read the lines of the file with fgets() and extract the words in each line with strtok(). Study the documentation for these functions, e.g.: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: @SouradeepSinha: As mentioned by @rubber boots just give it another  try. Also post the actual contents of your `.dat` files.

Comment: Thanks @rubberboots for the link. I'll read up now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asks for code, shows not attempt to solve it.

Comment: @1336087 I haven't been given the .dat file yet. I'm supposed to make one of my own in the given format. The grader will use her own .dat file with all possible test cases.

Comment: `while(2==fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &value1, &value2)){ //do stuff}`

Comment: @rubberboots Thank you for the help. Solved it finally.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @rubberboots for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("user.dat", "r");
    const char s[2] = ", ";
    char *token;
    int i;
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        char line[20];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(line, s);
            for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {   
                    printf("%s\t",token);
                    token = strtok(NULL,s);
                } else {
                    printf("%d\n",atoi(token));
                }       
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        perror("user.dat");
    }   
}
```

user.dat file:

1000, 76

0095, 81

2910, 178

0001, 1

Output:

1000    76

0095    81

2910    178

0001    1

Comment: Curious, why print the string version of what was read for the first number and use a number version for the second number?  Would not is be more consistent to either print both as strings or both as numbers?

Comment: Assignment woes. It doesn't make much sense to me as well. I guess the professor wanted us to learn and kill two birds with one printf statement. :P