# CSV File Input in C using Structures

Tags: c, csv

I want to print the data from `.csv` file line by line which is separated by `comma` delimeter.

This code prints the garbage value .

```
enum gender{ M, F };

struct student{
     int stud_no;
     enum gender stud_gen;
     char stud_name[100];
     int stud_marks;
};

void main()
{
   struct student s[60];
   int i=0,j,roll_no,marks,k,select;
   FILE *input;
   FILE *output;

   struct student temp;


    input=fopen("Internal test 1 Marks MCA SEM 1 oct 2014 - CS 101.csv","r");
    output=fopen("out.txt","a");

    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file...!!!");

    }

  while(fscanf(input,"%d,%c,%100[^,],%d", &s[i].stud_no,&s[i].stud_gen,&s[i].stud_name,&s[i].stud_marks)!=EOF)
  {

    printf("\n%d,%c,%s,%d", s[i].stud_no,s[i].stud_gen,s[i].stud_name,s[i].stud_marks);
    i++;
  }

}
```

I also tried the code from: [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c) But it prints only the `n`th field. I want to display all fields line by line.

Here is my sample input. 
`1401,F,FERNANDES SUZANNA ,13
1402,M,PARSEKAR VIPUL VILAS,14
1403,M,SEQUEIRA CLAYTON DIOGO,8
1404,M,FERNANDES GLENN ,17
1405,F,CHANDRAVARKAR TANUSHREE ROHIT,15`

Comment: Minor: `%100[^,]` --> `%99[^,]`

Comment: Suggest posting sample input.

Comment: It is generally much easier to read the entire line at a time and then parse each line with `strtok` or the like. Much more flexible and less prone to one stray char in the input file corrupting all data.

Comment: You should be checking `while(fscanf(input,...)==4)`. Checking `!= EOF` doesn't guarantee that `fscanf` succeeded.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The link i provided at the end prints only the nth field. How can I change it to all fields?

Comment: If you look at what the example shows. `getfield(char* line, int num)` creatively uses a `for` loop the get `All` fields from the comma separated line. However `int num` limits the return of the function to the `requested field` (num). You can work with that approach and read all fields. `strtok` is fairly simple. On the `first` call to `strtok` a pointer to the `line` is passed to get the `first` field. `All` remaining calls to `strtok` for the remaining fields replace `line` with `NULL` until `strtok` returns `NULL` signifying no more fields to read.

Comment: Note that your sample data is simple because no field contains commas embedded within it.  Full support for CSV format (see [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)) requires support for double quotes around fields, which can then embed double quotes by two adjacent double quotes. A field in double quotes can hold commas.

Answer (score 3):

While there are a number of ways to parse any line into components, one way that can really increase understanding is to use a `start` and `end` pointer to work down each line identifying the `commas`, replacing them with `null-terminators (i.e. '\0' or just 0)`, reading the field, restoring the comma and moving to the next field. This is just a manual application of `strtok`. The following example does that so you can see what is going on. You can, of course, replace use of the `start` and `end` pointers (`sp & p`, respectively) with `strtok`.

Read through the code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* maximum number of student to initially allocate */
#define MAXS 256

enum gender { M, F };

typedef struct {                /* create typedef to struct         */
    int stud_no;
    enum gender stud_gen;
    char *stud_name;
    int stud_marks;
} student;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("filename.csv please...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;          /* pointer to use with getline ()   */
    ssize_t read = 0;           /* characters read by getline ()    */
    size_t n = 0;               /* number of bytes to allocate      */
    student **students = NULL;  /* ptr to array of stuct student    */
    char *sp = NULL;            /* start pointer for parsing line   */
    char *p = NULL;             /* end pointer to use parsing line  */
    int field = 0;              /* counter for field in line         */
    int cnt = 0;                /* counter for number allocated     */
    int it = 0;                 /* simple iterator variable         */

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");  /* open file , read only            */
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }

    students = calloc (MAXS, sizeof (*students)); /* allocate 256 ptrs set to NULL */

    /* read each line in input file preserving 1 pointer as sentinel NULL */
    while (cnt < MAXS-1 && (read = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {

        sp = p = line;      /* set start ptr and ptr to beginning of line */
        field = 0;          /* set/reset field to 0 */

        students[cnt] = malloc (sizeof (**students));   /* alloc each stuct with malloc */

        while (*p)          /* for each character in line   */
        {
            if (*p == ',')  /* if ',' end of field found    */
            {
                *p = 0;     /* set as null-term char (temp) */

                if (field == 0) students[cnt]->stud_no    = atoi (sp);
                if (field == 1) {
                    if (*sp == 'M') {
                        students[cnt]->stud_gen   = 0;
                    } else {
                        students[cnt]->stud_gen   = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (field == 2) students[cnt]->stud_name  = strdup (sp);    /* strdup allocates for you */

                *p = ',';   /* replace with original ','    */
                sp = p + 1; /* set new start ptr start pos  */
                field++;    /* update field count           */
            }
            p++;            /* increment pointer p          */
        }
        students[cnt]->stud_marks = atoi (sp);    /* read stud_marks (sp alread set to begin) */

        cnt++;              /* increment students count     */
    }
    
    fclose (fp);            /* close file stream            */
    
    if (line)               /* free memory allocated by getline     */
        free (line);

    /* iterate over all students and print  */
    printf ("\nThe students in the class are:\n\n");
    while (students[it])
    {
        printf ("  %d   %c   %-30s   %d\n",
                students[it]->stud_no, (students[it]->stud_gen) ? 'F' : 'M', students[it]->stud_name, students[it]->stud_marks);
        it++;
    }
    printf ("\n");
    
    /* free memory allocated to struct */
    it = 0;
    while (students[it])
    {
        if (students[it]->stud_name)
            free (students[it]->stud_name);
        free (students[it]);
        it++;
    }
    if (students)
        free (students);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** added condition on loop that `cnt < MAXS-1` to preserve at least one pointer in `students` `NULL` as a sentinel allowing iteration.)

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/people.dat
1401,F,FERNANDES SUZANNA ,13
1402,M,PARSEKAR VIPUL VILAS,14
1403,M,SEQUEIRA CLAYTON DIOGO,8
1404,M,FERNANDES GLENN ,17
1405,F,CHANDRAVARKAR TANUSHREE ROHIT,15
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/stud_struct dat/people.dat

The students in the class are:

  1401   F   FERNANDES SUZANNA                13
  1402   M   PARSEKAR VIPUL VILAS             14
  1403   M   SEQUEIRA CLAYTON DIOGO           8
  1404   M   FERNANDES GLENN                  17
  1405   F   CHANDRAVARKAR TANUSHREE ROHIT    15
```

**valgrind memcheck:**

I have updated the code slightly to insure all allocated memory was freed to prevent against any memory leaks. Simple things like the automatic allocation of memory for `line` by `getline` or failing to close a file stream can result in small memory leaks. Below is the `valgrind` memcheck confirmation.

```
valgrind ./bin/stud_struct dat/people.dat
==11780== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11780== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11780== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11780== Command: ./bin/stud_struct dat/people.dat
==11780==

The students in the class are:

  1401   F   FERNANDES SUZANNA                13
  1402   M   PARSEKAR VIPUL VILAS             14
  1403   M   SEQUEIRA CLAYTON DIOGO           8
  1404   M   FERNANDES GLENN                  17
  1405   F   CHANDRAVARKAR TANUSHREE ROHIT    15

==11780==
==11780== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11780==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11780==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 2,966 bytes allocated
==11780==
==11780== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11780==
==11780== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11780== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: I suggest removing `if(line)` and `if (students[it]->stud_name)`.   You told me so yourself :-)

Comment: @AllanWind - but there we are only iterating within the allocated AND assigned group. I am about to drop an edit to clear up the confusion.

Comment: @AllanWind if you look, the loop is over `while (students[it])` which are the pointers that were allocated and assigned with `students[cnt] = malloc (sizeof (**students));` all others are initialized all `0` (`NULL`) with `calloc()`. So in this case we are safe. The `if` however is unnecessary, as `students[cnt]->stud_name  = strdup (sp);` would set the `stud_name` pointer `NULL` if allocation within `strdup()` failed making is safe to pass to `free()` without the check. (but thank you for following up on this old post and keeping me on my toes `:)`

Comment: Did need to add `while (cnt < MAXS-1 && (read = getline(...` to preserve at least 1 `NULL` pointer as a sentinel for iterating. There was a benefit to this revisit.

Comment: I didn't, btw, as the issue I worked on was focusing on the memory leak.  Rather than sync copies of your code what about just adding a link to this one, or even close the others as duplicates?  It's a really nice write-up, my only constructive feedback would be to introduce some functions.