# Why program show me too few arguments for call

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"student.h"
int main()
{
    // student 1
    
    STUDENT lux = Createstudent("2003056789-lux aa ren");
    printf("NAME：%s\n", GetNameFromStudent(lux));


    // student 2
    
    STUDENT a = Createstudent("2004069876-bb cc");
    printf("NAME：%s\n", GetNameFromStudent(a));
    printstudent(a);

    // student 3
    
    STUDENT b = Createstudent("2003081234-DD EE gg");
    printf("NAME：%s\n", GetNameFromStudent(b));
    printstudent(b);

    // student 4
    STUDENT c = Createstudent("2003074521-QQ RR YY");
    printf("NAME：%s\n", GetNameFromStudent(c));
    printstudent(c);

    // student 5
    STUDENT d = Createstudent("2003017623-MM NN JJ");
    printf("NAME：%s\n", GetNameFromStudent(d));
    printstudent(d);
    return 0;
}
```

**header.file** this is my header.file

```
#pragma once

#define MAXSIZE   25

typedef struct student
{
    int studentnum;
    char firstname[MAXSIZE];
    char lasttname[MAXSIZE];
    char middelname[MAXSIZE];
}STUDENT;


STUDENT Createstudent(int, char[], char[], char[]);
void printstudent(STUDENT);
```

the program asks me to print 5 different students and need to use a header.file
I am not sure why had a C2198 error on my program
I try to separate the student but I don't know how?

Comment: What is the declaration of `CreateStudent()`? How many parameters does it have?

Comment: @Gardener https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2198?view=msvc-170 it's the error message in the question title

Comment: You probably shouldn't be putting all the parameters in a single string. Maybe it should be `Createstudent("2003017623-MM",  "NN ", "JJ");`

Comment: @Gardener I add my header.file

Comment: @Barmar so i don't need STUDENT lux = any more?

Comment: @Gardener sorry, i didn't get it? wherei  should change my call to Createstudent

Comment: I was just showing how to call the function, not what you do with the result. That doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype says `STUDENT Createstudent(int, char[], char[], char[]);` takes 4 arguments (`int, char[], char[], char[]`) but you call it `STUDENT lux = Createstudent("2003056789-lux aa ren");` with 1 `char []` argument "2003056789-lux aa ren".

You need to parse the string into individual elements, for instance, using `sscanf(s, "%d-%s%s%s", &s->studentnum, s->firstname, s->middlename, s->lastname)`.  Your second data entry only has 2 space separated words, so you need to figure out if that is bad data, or one of the 3 strings are optional.  For instance, if you were only able to read 3 fields (`sscanf()` tells you how many fields) then `s->lastname = s->middlename; s->middlename = NULL;`

This or very similar problem has been discussed a number of times so use the search feature if you need more help.  For instance: [CSV File Input in C using Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695399/csv-file-input-in-c-using-structures/26695732)

Comment: so i need to change my header.file?

Comment: i try to creat a new question but system doesn't allow me do that : (

Comment: STUDENT Createstudent sscanf(s, "%d-%s%s%s", &s->studentnum, s->firstname, s->middlename, s->lastname)  should i change like that?

Comment: Try.  Start small with just one record.  You need to put some effort into this if you want to learn.