# Reading Strings/words and integers from input file

Tags: c, string, file-io

I want to write a little program to read lines from a given .csv/.txt file and print out specific details based on user input.

I'm currently working with a

```
FILE *input = fopen("Example.csv", "r");
```

and the input looks like this:

```
Test000, 40, 0, empty
Test001, 0, -41, empty
```

Now if I try to to *fscanf()* from input, it only sets the first char[] and ignores the other variables.

My *fscanf()* call looks like this:

```
fscanf(input, "%s , %d , %d , %s", name, &timeA, &timeB, info);

# I'm calling fscanf(...) inside of while()-condition.
# while (fscanf(...) == 4) { *apply logic here* }
```

So, with this code, *fscanf()* only ever sets name to 'Test000,', then '40', '0', 'empty' etc., but ignores timeA, timeB, and info.

They are defined as:

```
char name[51];
int  timeA = 0;
int  timeB = 0;
char info[51];
```

I really don't know how to circumvent this problem. Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try without the space between `%s` and the comma, and maybe initialize strings for safety `char *name = malloc(51);`

Comment: Didn't work, I tried this before.

Comment: `fscanf()` treats characters until it encounters white-space as a single string (`char[]`) - so the best option for you would be to remove the commas in your `.txt` file, and your make your fscanf the following: `fscanf(input, "%s %d %d %s", name, &timeA, &timeB, info);` - your data should look like: `Test000 40 0 empty`. That's the most straightforward way of making it work.

Comment: May I suggest a basic CSV parser? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349263/c-regex-how-to-match-any-string-ending-with-or-any-empty-string/32351114#32351114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fscanf()` treats consecutive characters until it encounters white-space as part of a single string (`char[]`) - so the best option for you would be to remove the commas in your `.txt` file, and make your fscanf the following: `fscanf(input, "%s %d %d %s", name, &timeA, &timeB, info);` - your data should look like: `Test000 40 0 empty`. That's the most straightforward way of making it work.

If you want it to work with your current data format, `fscanf()` may not be the best option. You would be better off using some functions form `<string.h>`.

```
char data[512];
fgets(data, sizeof (data), input);

strcpy(name, strtok(data), ","));
timea = (int) strtol(strtok(data, ","), NULL, 10);
timea = (int) strtol(strtok(data, ","), NULL, 10);
strcpy(info, strtok(data, ","));
```

(`strcpy` and `strtok` are both avaible in `<string.h>`, `strtol()` is available in `<stdlib.h>`)

`strcpy` is used to copy "strings".

`strtok` splits a string (Note that it modifies the string it is passed!).

`strtol` converts a string to an long (which we cast to int).

There are more secure versions of some of the functions available (i.e. `strtok_r()` and `strtol()` also comes in an `int` version (so you don't need to cast its return value to `int`) called `strtod()`

If you are on a *nix system, it would be a good idea to run `man function_name()` (e.g. `man strtok`) to get a better idea of the function prototype and what it does/how it behaves etc. - or you can always read the man pages online, for example the [FreeBSD Online Manual Pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtok&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) where you can search for the function name and read the relevent man page.

Answer (score 1):

A scanset could be used. `%50[^,]` will read up to 50 characters or to a comma.

```
fscanf(input, " %50[^,], %d , %d , %50s", name, &timeA, &timeB, info);
```

Note the space before `&50[^,]` to consume leading whitespace.

Check the return of `fscanf`. In this case 4 will be returned if all four items are successfully scanned.