# Downsampling a CSV by a factor of 10 and saving it into another file

Tags: python, c, pandas, csv, awk

I have a .csv file with many rows (i.e. 3000 to 4000) in which each row represent an event with a sampling rate of **1Hz**. I want to create another .csv in which each row represent an event with a sampling rate of **0.1Hz**.

In other words I want to go from a .csv with a resolution of 1 event per second to a .csv with a resolution of 1 event per 10 seconds.

I need the pseudo-code for a language agnostic algorithm, but also an implementation (preferably in C).

Comment: You're going to implement this in all the languages you tagged?

Comment: You mean `awk '(NR-1) % 10 == 0' foo.csv` ?

Comment: in commandline? is awk namefile or command?

Comment: Are you familiar with any of the languages you tagged? Choose the one you are most familiar with - or use python if you don't know any pl :)

Comment: @DannyLeePiloote just hack it into your shell

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349263/c-regex-how-to-match-any-string-ending-with-or-any-empty-string/32351114#32351114 for a basic CSV parser. Adapt as needed.

Comment: 3000 lines is not a big CSV file.  3,000,000 starts being big, but isn't all that big unless the lines are very long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too clear in which language you want to implement it. Here is a language agnostic plan:

- Ask the user for the file to load
- Open the file in Read
- Open another file in Write mode
- Iterate through the Read file line by line.
- Keep a counter and increment it everytime you read a line in your loop.
- `if counter mod 10 == 0` then you append that line to the Write file.
- close both file when you are done.

Here is a higher level python implementation that uses pandas to do the low-level manipulation for us.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Boilerplate to simulate the author initial condition
# Creating a sample CSV file with a 1Hz resolution
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-08', periods=3000, freq='s')
df.to_csv(path_or_buf="input.csv",index=False)

# Read the file
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
# Convert to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
# Resampling down to 0.1Hz
df = df.resample('10s', on='time').first()
df.to_csv(path_or_buf="output.csv",index=False)
```

this yield:

```
2020-01-08 00:00:00
2020-01-08 00:00:10
2020-01-08 00:00:20
2020-01-08 00:00:30
2020-01-08 00:00:40
```

Comment: If it could be in C, would be better as my experience in C is better, but was seeing which language lead to the shortest program!

Comment: In Python this is a 5-6 liner

Comment: In `awk` it is a 1-liner... I wonder, why the OP isn't satisfied with that, too easy? ;)

Comment: Perl would do it in one line too; it would be more inscrutable than the Awk version, though.

Comment: I gotta learn that awk then