# How to split a file in rows or columns in c

Tags: c

I am trying to split a line from a file in different parts separated by a single space, but it doesn`t work... So my question is: How can i split my line in different parts and do that for every single line of the file and then put those parts in dynamically allocated vectors/matrix? Or by columns as well. Tell me as you see fit.

The file looks like this:

```
BERLIN CAR 1 U        
BERLIN CAR 1 R 
BUCHAREST JACKET 2 D
NEW_YORK DOLL 7 U 
BERLIN ROBOT 5 L 
BUCHAREST BALL 4 L
```

I want to do this.
Example:

```
Locations[i]={"BERLIN","BERLIN","BUCHAREST","NEW_YORK"."BERLIN","BUCHAREST"}
TOYS[j]={"CAR","CAR","JACKET","DOLL","ROBOT","BALL"}
NUMBER[k]={1,1,2,7,5,4}
LETTER[l]={'U','R','D','U','L','L'}
```

My code so far (MAX_STRING_LENGTH is defined to 30 ) :

```
int i;
char *p,**a,delim[]=" ";
a=malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    a[i]=calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH,sizeof(char));
}
while(!feof(stdin))
{
    fgets(*a,500,stdin);
    p=strtok(*a,delim);
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof(stdin))
{
    fgets(*a,500,stdin);`: so the last line is tokenized twice [why is  while(!feof()) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Put the link to the famous *why is `while(!feof())` always wrong*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: I think `a=malloc(100 * sizeof(char));` should be `a=malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));`.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. - The first allocation should be for the pointers that will point to each line, therefore it should probable be`a=malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: @ryyker: Oh, thanks. I've edited my comment.

Comment: The other question is should the next statement be `a[i]=calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH,sizeof(char));` or `a[i]=calloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1,1);`

Comment: @ryyker it`s the same thing i think because char has the size of 1

Comment: In the `!feof` loop `a` does not advance to the next element. Also, `strtok` only extracts the first token (the city) so that needs a loop to extract the other fields.  Also, you must count the number of file records that were read. The code lacks a `struct` to store these fields, and an array of that `struct` is better than separate arrays of each field. I suggest you find some examples of similar code: there are plenty.

Comment: @WeatherVane that is exactly what i am doing . i have a matrix in which every single element is a struct, but i don`t know if the fields retains those things and if i can acces those fields independetly,Like the field from my structure called destinations is a vector of strings and i can play with it like so? i simply lack the information and i can`t`find it anywhere and i am new to programming.....

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor can you include in your post the definition of the struct? Also you can have an array of `struct carinfo` or a struct that contains all cars. Both are valid solution but depending on your needs, one can be better than the other.

Comment: @Pablo i have added my entire code.. sorry if i am being stressful...

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor I made an update of my answer with an example of how to implement your code.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is the correct function, however you are using it wrong.

> *man strtok*
>
> The `strtok()` function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more nonempty tokens.
>   **On the first call to `strtok()`, the string to be parsed should be specified
>   in `str`. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str`
>   must be `NULL`**.

I made the most important part of the quote bold.

Also bear in mind that `strtok` modifies the source, if you need the source
afterwards, you have to make a copy.

```
// assuming that line is either a char[] or char*

char *token = strtok(line, " ");
if(token == NULL)
{
    // error detection
}

while(token = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    // do the work
}
```

Also I recommend not to use `sizeof(<data type>)` in
`malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` calls. It's easy to overlook a `*` and make
mistakes. Better:

```
int *myarray = malloc(size * sizeof *myarray);

// or

int *mayarray = calloc(size, sizeof *myarray);
```

Using `sizeof *var` is better because it will always returns the correct size.

One last thing:

```
while(!feof(stdin))
```

See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

better

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
{
    // do the work here
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here you have a sample implementation using `strtok`. My implementation uses
an array of `MAP`s. Look at the way I construct/destruct the the `MAP` objects and how the memory is allocated. Obviously this can be done with less code and less `strdup`s, but I think this shows more precisely how to use these functions. You can use this code as your base or just use it as a basic idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct{
    char *destination;
    char *type_present;
    int no_available_presents;
    char *direction;
} MAP;

MAP *create_map(const char *dest, const char *type, int present, const char *dir);
void free_map(MAP *map);
void print_map(MAP *map);


MAP *create_map(const char *dest, const char *type, int present, const char *dir)
{
    MAP *map = calloc(1, sizeof *map);
    if(map == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int errors = 0;

    if(!(map->destination = strdup(dest)))
        errors++;

    if(!(map->type_present = strdup(type)))
        errors++;

    if(!(map->direction = strdup(dir)))
        errors++;

    map->no_available_presents = present;

    if(!errors)
        return map;

    free_map(map);
    return NULL;
}

void free_map(MAP *map)
{
    if(map == NULL)
        return;

    free(map->destination);
    free(map->type_present);
    free(map->direction);
    free(map);
}

void print_map(MAP *map)
{
    if(map == NULL)
    {
        puts("(null)");
        return;
    }

    printf("destination: %s\n", map->destination);
    printf("type:        %s\n", map->type_present);
    printf("present:     %d\n", map->no_available_presents);
    printf("direction:   %s\n", map->direction);
}

int main(char argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    if(argc != 1 && argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [database]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if(argc == 1)
        fp = stdin;
    else
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno)); 
        return 1;
    }

    MAP **maps = NULL;
    size_t map_len = 0;

    char line[1024];
    const char *delim = " \r\n";

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        int pres;
        char *dest = NULL, *type = NULL, *dir = NULL, *token;

        token = strtok(line, delim);
        dest = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        type = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        pres = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        dir = strdup(token);

        if(dest == NULL || type == NULL || dir == NULL)
        {
            // ignore line
            free(dest);free(type);free(dir);
            continue;
        }

        MAP *new_map = create_map(dest, type, pres, dir);

        if(new_map == NULL)
        {
            // ignore line
            free(dest);free(type);free(dir);
            continue;
        }

        MAP **tmp_map = realloc(maps, (map_len + 1) * sizeof *tmp_map);

        if(tmp_map == NULL)
        {
            // ignore line
            free_map(new_map);
            free(dest);free(type);free(dir);
            continue;
        }

        maps = tmp_map;
        maps[map_len++] = new_map;
        free(dest);free(type);free(dir);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < map_len; ++i)
    {
        print_map(maps[i]);
        puts("---");
        free_map(maps[i]);
    }

    free(maps);


    if(fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
destination: BERLIN
type:        CAR
present:     1
direction:   U
---
destination: BERLIN
type:        CAR
present:     1
direction:   R
---
destination: BUCHAREST
type:        JACKET
present:     2
direction:   D
---
destination: NEW_YORK
type:        DOLL
present:     7
direction:   U
---
destination: BERLIN
type:        ROBOT
present:     5
direction:   L
---
destination: BUCHAREST
type:        BALL
present:     4
direction:   L
---
```

Comment: I did that check with strtok, i thought that was irrelevant to this problem . So i understand that my code has a lot o little problmes...

Comment: @MateiCristianNicusor do you mean the first `token == NULL` check? More important is that you have to loop `strtok` until you get `NULL`, otherwise you only retrieve the first token.

Comment: The read function `fgets` retains any newline in the input string. In the context of `strtok` it would strip that by including newline perms in the delimitor string, say `strtok(.... , " \n\r")`

Comment: @WeatherVane that's a good advice, I've never thought of doing that. I usually strip the the `\n` before anything else.