# What's the meaning of "&&" when operated by a char * on a char in C++?

Tags: c++

I came across a code which extracted a token(c string) from a given string,but I am confused by the 5th line:`tok && *tok`. I just cannot figure out this operation's result. Does anybody happen to know?

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: this code has not sense (but is formally ok). Compute expression and be not interrest in result. Maybe wrong copy&paste?

Comment: `&&` is logical and.  It's taking the logical and of `tok` (effectively `tok != NULL`) and `*tok` (effectively `*tok != 0`).

Comment: @StephenNewell is correct. In other words, the expression evaluates to `true` if and only if `tok` points to an non-nul character.

Comment: @Jacek Cz I don't understand it either... The codes aimed to read a CSV file.  If you are curious about that...here is the link where I saw these codes: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c#answer-12911465).  Share me your opinion if you figure out what he is doing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It checks first if the pointer (`tok`) isn't `nullptr` (pointing to nothing), then if the pointer isn't `nullptr`, it checks if it points to memory where the value (`*tok`) isn't `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you! And one more thing, will error message occur if `tok` turns out to be a null pointer or is a `'\0'`?

Comment: You're welcome. If `num > 0` and `tok == NULL || *tok == '\0'` it will return `NULL`, else it will return `tok`. An error message can appear if you check the return value of the function when you call it and print a message if it returned `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the conditional expression, and it is checking that `tok` is not `nullptr` and that `*tok`, or the character, is not the "nul" character `'\0'`.

In a C-style for-loop, you have the initalizer, the condition, and the increment expressions. The condition here is that `tok` evaluates to true, then `*tok` evaluates to true.

This can only occur if `tok` is not `nullptr`, and the character pointed to (`*tok`) is not `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of && remains the same. It is still a logical operator. That statement is equivalent to

```
(tok != nullptr) && (*tok != '\0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can any point out what the below portion means?

```
{
    if (!--num)
        return tok;
}
```

I'm most interested in the `if (!--num)`.  It's not making sense to me.  In my head it reads as `if NOT num = num - num.`  It's really cramping my brain.

I know ! is the NOT operator, but the --num just doesn't compute in my brain.