# Read file with comma separated hex values into array in C

Tags: c

How I can read a text file with comma separated hex values e.g. `0x58,0xA9,0x00` and put its values as elements of an array e.g. `LR0` 
I need to replace this hard-coded with reading from the file:

```
const unsigned char LR0[] = {0x58,0xA9,0x00}
```

Here is what I wrote so far. `printf("%c", ch);` shows me what I need but when I uncomment `strcat(LR0, ch);` it fails at run time with a `segment fault`. I don't know if I should use `strcat` or anything else to append the elements of this `LR0` array.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#include <string.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                  

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   int ch;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   //const unsigned char LR0 [1024] = "";                                                                                                                                                                            
   const unsigned char LR0 [] = {};                                                                                                                                                                                  
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");                                                                                                                                                                                      
   if (fp == NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");                                                                                                                                                                     
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                                                                            
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){                                                                                                                                                                                   
      printf("%c", ch);                                                                                                                                                                                              
      //strcat(LR0, (char) ch);                                                                                                                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Sorry so basic question not able to fix it by googling etc. I am not a `C` developer and I am using gcc on linux. My text file does not contain lines so I cannot use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: You cannot write to a variable declared as a const in C, so when you are doing `strcat()` on `const unsigned char LR0[]` the program is throwing a segfault.

Comment: LR0 is declared as 0 length - so when you try to copy to it, you're trying to write to unallocated memory. which causes a segfault

Comment: @Gaurav Yes you can - just case the const away. It's not nice - but in C you actually can.

Comment: @Gaurav I have tried it with by removing `const` but as @fredrik mentioned already it still fails because LR0 is allocated as a 0-length array. Writing to it leads to a segfault.

Comment: @fredrik even with a "just case the const away", it is still UB to write to the `const` array.

Comment: gxmaxin  Are you interested in a standard C answer or one that works with your compiler's extensions to the language?

Comment: @chux thanks for help, I am using `gcc` on my desktop now but in the end I have to cross compile with `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` I would prefer standard C but if I that's makes it harder, an gcc option would be enough.

Comment: @chux UB yes, but it is possible and if you know what you're doing yo u can get away with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const unsigned char LR0 [] = {};` implies a zero length array - that is not standard C yet allowed with some compilers.

`strcat(LR0, (char) ch);` attempts to 1) write to a `const` array `LR0` and 2) write outside the array - it is only 0 length.  Both of the are *undefined behavior* (UB).

> I don't know if I should use strcat

Using `str...()` functions will not well handle input which may contain many `"0x00, 0x00, ..."`.

---

> How I can read a text file with comma separated hex values e.g. 0x58,0xA9,0x00 and put its values as elements of an array (?)

Read the file to determine its length and contents.  I suggest a pass for each.

The below is untested, yet hopefully enough to get OP started.  It has little error detection.

```
// Parse a text file like  "0x58,0xA9,0x00"
// Return byte count.  Return 0 on error.
size_t read_comma_hex(FILE *f, unsigned char *dest, size_t num) {
  rewind(f);
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
    if (i) {
      int ch = fgetc(f);

      // Add to tolerate white space before the ',' or after the the last number
      while (isspace(ch)) {
        ch = fgetc(f);
      }

      if (ch == EOF) break;    // no more data
      if (ch != ',') return 0; // Fail, as ',' expected
    }
    unsigned char hex;
    if (fscanf(f, "0x%hhx", &hex) != 1) return 0;   
    if (dest) dest[i] = hex;
  }
  return i;
}

void read_comma_hex_file(FILE *f) {
  size_t n =  read_comma_hex(f, NULL, SIZE_MAX);
  if (n == 0) return; // no data or failure

  // OP wants an array - research variable length array
  const unsigned char LR0[n];
  // Alternative: allocate memory instead of using an _array_. (not shown)

  // Read data into the array  
  read_comma_hex(f, LR0, n);

  // use LR0 and n some how
  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("0x%02hhX%s", LR0[i], i > 0 ? "," : "");
  } 
}
```

Comment: @gmaxin Given the sample format `"0x58,0xA9,0x00"`, I rejected your suggested edit as it does not detect errors properly.  I suspect your desire for the code change was due to wanting to also allow a new format: `"0x58,0xA9,0x00\n"`.  I amended the answer to tolerate whitespace at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code.

1. `LR0`  is declared as `const` with unspecified size which  is just pointer, writing to it may result in UB.
2. `strcat` needs it arguments as `char *` type but your second argument is of `char` type (`int ch;`).

   `strcat(LR0, (char) ch)`

You can use the `fscanf` with `,` as delimiter as below to read only the `hex` values discarding `,`.

```
int main() {                                                                                                                                                            
    FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                                            
    unsigned char LR0 [1024] = {};                                                                                                                                          
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");                                                                                                                                         
    if (fp == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                    
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");                                                                                                                        
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                               
    }

    int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                          
    while(fscanf(fp, "%c,", &LR0[i]) == 1){                                                                                                                                
        printf("%c", LR0[i++]);                                                                                                                                           
    }

    fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Comment: Point 1 is wrong, all you need to do is cast it away. But LR0 is allocated as a 0-length array. Wrinting to is will thus result in a segfault.

Comment: @fredrik Updated accordingly.

Comment: "writing to it may result in UB." - it is UB - due to `const`.  a "cast way" does not remove the UB-ness of writing - the underlying object is still a `const` array..  It is also UB to write outside the bounds of an array.  Yet a 0 length array it outside std C, so we are dealing with a language extension with its rules.