# importing and manipulating .csv files in c language

Tags: c, import

How can I import .csv file in c language and then manipulate the data accordingly. Like finding out mean of dataset ,finding median etc.

Comment: Probably duplicate, [check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911465/8784431)

Answer (score 0):

You can read file as text file. Separate columns by ',' and create arrays. Then you can do whatever you want with your arrays.