# How to read data from txt file>

Tags: c

I have a little problem with reading data from file. 
I need to read the name, lastname and phone number.
But the data is separated by '|'.

file e.g.

```
Matthew | McConaughey | 684299275

Humphrey | Bogart | 204050673

Mary | Tyler Moore | 503462885

Loretta | Young | 416211713
```

I wrote this function

```c
char name[20];
char lastname[40];
int number;

while(!feof(plik)){
int hpl=fscanf(filename, "%s | %s | %d", name, lastname, &number);
}
```

I have problem when in the file are two-member lastname like 'Tyler Moore', then fscanf return 2

I don't know how I can read them

That is possible to use one fscanf() function ?

Comment: have a look at this answer on 
 [instruct the fscanf() to look for another delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443267/specifying-a-format-for-fscanf-that-doesnt-contain-white-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

It is because, `scanf` family functions read until space. You can use [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to get whole line, and then parse it using  function multi_tok function that is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29789623/8842262