# How to read a CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file of the following format:

```
5,455,78,5
12245,4,78
1,455,4557,1,8,9
```

I have managed to open the file but I have no idea how to interpret the data. All the data is written in the first column, but I do not know how many rows there are or how many entries there is in each row.
This is my code for opening the file.

```
    printf("File chosen is: %s", file);
    
    int p = 0;
    
    FILE *myFile = NULL;
    
    myFile = fopen(file, "r");
    
    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if (myFile != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nFile read successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Try `fgets()`. It reads one line at a time, provided the buffer is large enough. Also remember to `fclose()` the file when you don't need it any more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c check whether this link solve your issue

Comment: Does your CSV file have lines with differing numbers of fields?

Answer (score 2):

This should parse your csv. After opening you file, read each line using [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm). Loop through until fgets returns NULL which indicates no line could be read and you reached the end of your file. Use [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse your line from fgets using the comma as your delimiter.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // file handling functions
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi
#include <string.h> // strtok

...

    char buffer[80];
    while (fgets(buffer, 80, myFile)) {
        // If you only need the first column of each row
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        if (token) {
            int n = atoi(token);
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }

        // If you need all the values in a row
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        while (token) { 
            // Just printing each integer here but handle as needed
            int n = atoi(token);
            printf("%d\n", n);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }

...
```

Comment: Check to see if it is NULL to continue or leave the for loop

Comment: Sorry, forget my comment, but the formatting of that part of the code is terrible...

Comment: How so? A for loop has three parts and each is clearly shown on a separate line.

Comment: Good to use `fgets()`.  `char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");` might return `NULL` too.

Comment: `strtok()` is inappropriate for parsing CSV files if any of the fields may be empty as it will consider any sequence of separators as a single separator.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting some code, but you don't mention what you wish to do with your data once you read it in.

I'll give you some pointers:

Use an array of known size to read your data into from the file and buffer it for processing. Run this in a loop. e.g.

```
  char buffer[1000];

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof (buffer), myFile))
  {
    char *data = strtok(buffer, ",");

    while (data !=NULL)
    {
        printf("Data %s\n", data);
        /* Further processing of data */

        data = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
  }

  fclose(myFile);
```

Process that buffer using `strtok` to separate out your strings. The token is the data delimiter which should be `','` but I'm not clear on whether you also have a newline character in there, but it needs to be consistent.

Handle your strings returned above.

Comment: I want to sort the data, by using a bubble sort, merge sort and q-sort. I will use a timing function to determine the time each sorting methods takes to sort an array of the data received from the file.

Comment: @ChrisBD What is the purpose of this line `data = strtok(NULL, ",");` ? Why are you trying to tokenize a `NULL`?

Comment: Actually you should have asked me why I wasn't looping through calling `data-strtok(NULL,",");` until data was `NULL`. `strtok` is called once on the data string being tested and then repeatedly called with `NULL` supplied until result is `NULL`. If you pass a non-NULL value it will restart from the beginning of the string being tested.

Comment: `strtok()` is inappropriate for parsing CSV files if any of the fields may be empty as it will consider any sequence of separators as a single separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
        tok && *tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *stream = fopen("yourfile.csv", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Choose a line to be given its elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = _strdup(line);
        i++;
        printf("Element %d would be %s\n", i, getfield(tmp, j));
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious, why `_strdup()` vs. just calling `getfield(line, j)`?

Comment: `strtok()` is inappropriate for parsing CSV files if any of the fields may be empty as it will consider any sequence of separators as a single separator.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains lines with lists of numbers, here is a simple parser:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// return the number of integer in the line, accept empty fields as 0
int parse_line(const char *line, int *array, int len) {
    const char *p = line;
    char *endp;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < len) {
        long n = strtol(p, &endp, 10);
        if (n > INT_MAX) n = INT_MAX;
        if (n < INT_MIN) n = INT_MIN;
        if (*endp == ',' || *endp == ';' || *endp == '\n')
            endp++;
        else
            break;
        array[i++] = n;
        p = endp;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    FILE *myFile = stdin;
    if (argc > 2) {
        const char *file = argv[1];
        printf("File chosen is: %s\n", file);
        myFile = fopen(file, "r");
        if (myFile == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    char line[100];
    int array[50];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, myFile)) {
        int n = parse_line(line, array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d%c", array[i], ",\n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```