# Reading a .csv and then saving it into arrays in C

Tags: c

I am quite new to C programming and I was wondering how I can save 2 .csv files into an integer array and then print it. The first .csv file is a 2d array and the 2nd is a 1d array.

Comment: Hello, please provide a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: Have you gone through this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c), yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read .CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: Read a character. If it is a comma: the current field has ended. If it is a LF: the current record has ended. Otherwise/default: the character should be added to the current field. Rinse,repeat. Good luck.

Comment: If your input is numeric, the `strtoX` (e.g. `strtol()`, `strtoul()`, `strtod()`, etc..) are custom made for parsing values from lines of input. Along with `strtok()` (or `strsep()` if empty-fields are possible) or `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` if the number of fields are fixed, or `strspn()` and `strcspn()` combinations...

Answer (score 0):

you did not post any code so i do not have any example where are you facing problem.
but in .csv file fields are separated with commas so you can use `strtok` to separate the values and store them in the desired array.

you should also take care of the size of the array too. you can make it dynamic using `realloc`.

you can use  [read .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c) this as an example.