# How to read a .csv file in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I have written the `host code` in `OpenCL`. But I need first to `read` data from a `.csv file.` I need to make sure that what I did in reading the file is correct. (I am not sure if this is the way of reding a file in opencl)

1- I put the `read file function` which is written in `c++` before the `main` .

2 - then, I put function to mix the data. Also before the `main`

3- In the `main` function, I call the above two function to read the data and then mix it.

4- then I write the part of host code which include(platform, device, context, queue, buffers....etc)

This is my code:

```
 bool read_data_set(string filename, array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset) {
    int field0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
        field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21;
    char comma;
    int line = 0;

    ifstream myfile(filename);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile
            >> field0 >> comma
            >> field1 >> comma
            >> field2 >> comma
            >> field3 >> comma
            >> field4 >> comma
            >> field5 >> comma
            >> field6 >> comma
            >> field7 >> comma
            >> field8 >> comma
            >> field9 >> comma
            >> field10 >> comma
            >> field11 >> comma
            >> field12 >> comma
            >> field13 >> comma
            >> field14 >> comma
            >> field15 >> comma
            >> field16 >> comma
            >> field17 >> comma
            >> field18 >> comma
            >> field19 >> comma
            >> field20 >> comma
            >> field21)
        {


            array<int, 20> inner_array{ field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11,
            field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20 };
            array_X_dataset[line] = inner_array;
            array_Y_dataset[line] = field21;
            line++;

        }

        myfile.close();

    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//functoin to randomly mix the dataset.
void mix_dataset(array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset) {
    size_t len = array_X_dataset.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        size_t swap_index = rand() % len;  // Random number between 0 and len-1.
        if (i == swap_index)
            continue;

        array<int, 20> data_point{  };
        data_point = array_X_dataset[i];
        array_X_dataset[i] = array_X_dataset[swap_index];
        array_X_dataset[swap_index] = data_point;
        int Y = array_Y_dataset[i];
        array_Y_dataset[i] = array_Y_dataset[swap_index];
        array_Y_dataset[swap_index] = Y;
    }
}
int main()
{
    // Read dataset from file.
    string filename = ".//Dataset.csv";
    static array<array<int, 20>, 5430> array_X_dataset{};
    static array<int, 5430> array_Y_dataset{};
    size_t rows = sizeof(array_X_dataset) / sizeof(array_X_dataset[0]);
    size_t cols = sizeof(array_X_dataset[0]) / sizeof(int);

    bool error = read_data_set(filename, array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset);
    if (error) {
        cout << "Exiting with error while reading dataset file " << filename << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
  
// Randomly mix the dataset and printout.
// Initialize the seed.
    srand(3);
    mix_dataset(array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset);

    int array_X_set[5430][20];
    int array_Y_set[5430];

    // copy contents of the mixed std::arrays into plain arrays  
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            array_X_set[i][j] = array_X_dataset[i][j];
        array_Y_set[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
    }
    
    int X_train[4344][20] = {};
    int Y_train[4344] = {};
    int X_test[1086][20] = {};
    int Y_test[1086] = {};


    //split the dataset using 5 - fold cross validation
    float sum_accurecy = 0.0;
    int fold = 1;
   // cout << "inseret fold num " << endl;
    //cin >> fold;
    split_dataset(fold, array_X_set, array_Y_set, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test);
        
//--------------------------host code--------------------------------------------------------------//

    // Search for an openCL platform
    cl_platform_id fpga_paltform = NULL;
    if (clGetPlatformIDs(1, &fpga_paltform, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Unable to get platform_id\n");
    return 1;
  }

    // Search for an openCL device
    cl_device_id fpga_device = NULL;
    if (clGetDeviceIDs(fpga_paltform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &fpga_device, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    ..............
.................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the OpenCL programming model contains two codes, host code(.c/.cpp..) which runs on host(CPU) and kernel code(.cl) which runs on device(eg:GPU..).

### Host Side :

1. you'll initialize the data(like you do in any C program)
2. Create a buffer object using clCreateBuffer() (think of it as reserving memory on the device) (similarly allocate for output)
3. Send the initialized data to the device using clEnqueueWriteBuffer()(to the earlier reserved space)
4. Invoke the kernel using clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()(now the device has kernel code and data)

### Device Side:

5. Execute the kernel code
6. Write the output data to reserved space by host

### Host Side:

7. Afer device completes its execution host reads the data from the Device using clEnqueueReadBuffer().

With this flow, you've offloaded the computation to the device and read the output to host.

### NOTE:

This explanation is not 100% accurate, I tried to explain it in a simpler manner. I would suggest you read chapter-3 from (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf)