# How i can store the data read from the file in new array and print all the data from the new array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, file, pointers

Thus I have read the data from file and print in display but I cannot save the data read from file into new array.

file data eg:

```
23,56
78,65
```

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr = fopen("datasetLR1.txt", "r");
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("File not found or allocated!");
        exit(1);
     }
    int str[85];
    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptr) != NULL) { 
        printf(fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptr));
    }
    system("pause");
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed the "`printf` line" to `printf("%s", str);`

Comment: Related: [Read .csv file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change theese parts:

```
    char rowBuffer[85];  // fgets want's a char buffer
    while (fgets(rowBuffer, sizeof(rowBuffer), ptr) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", rowBuffer);  // We do not want to read and print again at the same time
    }
```

Your solution does nothing (yet) to interpret the integer values.

Also, as commented by others, `printf(src)` is unsafe in-case the data contains formatting content like "... %s ..." that can mess with your program execution. `puts(str)` (if you want to add LF) or `printf("%s", str)` for literal string reproduction.