# How to read an csv file into an struct

Tags: arrays, c, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file of the following format:

```
1.00,1.00,hawaiian_m,1.00,1/1/2015,11:38:36,13.25,13.25,M,Classic,"Sliced Ham, Pineapple, Mozzarella Cheese",The Hawaiian Pizza
2.00,2.00,classic_dlx_m,1.00,1/1/2015,11:57:40,16.00,16,M,Classic,"Pepperoni, Mushrooms, Red Onions, Red Peppers, Bacon",The Classic Deluxe Pizza
3.00,2.00,five_cheese_l,1.00,1/1/2015,11:57:40,18.50,18.5,L,Veggie,"Mozzarella Cheese, Provolone Cheese, SmokedGouda Cheese, Romano Cheese, Blue Cheese, Garlic",The Five Cheese Pizza
```

And put every column in the following struct:

```
typedef struct{

    float pizza_id;
    float order_id;
    char pizza_name_id[50];
    float quantity;
    char order_date[50];
    char order_time[50];
    float unit_price;
    float total_price;
    char pizza_size;
    char pizza_category[50];
    char pizza_ingredients[100];
    char pizza_name[50];



} order;
```

I tried the following code and didn't show up the pizza_ingredients part.

```
while (!feof(f))
    {
        read = fscanf(f,"%f,%f,%49[^,],%f,%49[^,],%49[^,],%f,%f,%c,%49[^,],%2047[^34],%49[^,]\n",
                    &or[linea].pizza_id,
                    &or[linea].order_id,
                    or[linea].pizza_name_id,
                    &or[linea].quantity,
                    or[linea].order_date,
                    or[linea].order_time,
                    &or[linea].unit_price,
                    &or[linea].total_price,
                    &or[linea].pizza_size,
                    or[linea].pizza_category,
                    or[linea].pizza_ingredients,
                    or[linea].pizza_name);
        linea++;
    }
```

Comment: You're skipping the comma before the ingredients but not the opening quote so the rest falls apart. You'd need to skip the closing quote too unless you want it in the name. Here's a very fragile example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ef4W7eaK6 Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/28321635/920069 would be better but you should also read [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) for both your code and the linked answer.

Comment: The problem you have is the classic CSV problem of quoted data with enclosed commas. You are likely best served by locating the quotes and replacing the enclosed commas with an obscure decoration character (e.g. substitute enclosed commas with `~` or the like). Then you can simply tokenize the line on commas with `strtok()` if you have no empty-fields to preserve, otherwise alternating `strspn()` and `strcspn()` works well (and will work on string-literals as the original string isn't modified). There are also some good C CSV libraries you can google.

Comment: CSV is a surprisingly tricky thing to parse. Not crazy hard but you can easily spend a couple hundred lines of code doing it right. If you cannot use an off-the-shelf library, you can at least study one.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide all of your codes for better debug

You have two problems that I have solved for you

`pizza_ingredients` should be like this: `\"%2047[^\"]\"` because you have some comma inside it, and at the end you should prevent new line also: `%49[^,\n]`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{

    float pizza_id;
    float order_id;
    char pizza_name_id[50];
    float quantity;
    char order_date[50];
    char order_time[50];
    float unit_price;
    float total_price;
    char pizza_size;
    char pizza_category[50];
    char pizza_ingredients[100];
    char pizza_name[50];
} order;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    int linea = 0;
    order or [3];

    while (!feof(f))
    {

        printf("Linea %d\n", linea);
        int read = fscanf(f, "%f,%f,%49[^,],%f,%49[^,],%49[^,],%f,%f,%c,%49[^,],\"%2047[^\"]\",%49[^,\n]\n",
                          & or [linea].pizza_id,
                          & or [linea].order_id,
                          or [linea].pizza_name_id,
                          & or [linea].quantity,
                          or [linea].order_date,
                          or [linea].order_time,
                          & or [linea].unit_price,
                          & or [linea].total_price,
                          & or [linea].pizza_size,
                          or [linea].pizza_category,
                          or [linea].pizza_ingredients,
                          or [linea].pizza_name);

        printf("pizza_id : %f, order_id : %f, pizza_name_id: %s, quantity: %f, order_date:%s, order_time: %s, unit_price:%f, total_price: %f, pizza_size:%c, pizza_category: %s, pizza_ingredients: %s, pizza_name: %s \n", or [linea].pizza_id, or [linea].order_id, or [linea].pizza_name_id, or [linea].quantity, or [linea].order_date, or [linea].order_time, or [linea].unit_price, or [linea].total_price, or [linea].pizza_size, or [linea].pizza_category, or [linea].pizza_ingredients, or [linea].pizza_name);

        linea++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```